# Determining size of array allocated via HeapAlloc()

Tags: c, winapi, memory, memory-management

I'm using WinAPI's [`HeapAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx) function for allocating memory, and I want to find out the size of it somewhere else in my code. Do I have to keep track of the sizes myself or is there another way?

Comment: Completely improper use of [**`sizeof`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) in your use with `sizeof(matches[lastMeal])` . It has *nothing* to do with the heap allocation from `HeapAlloc`

Comment: Oh.. so how would I find out the size of that array? Somewhere I read you could just use sizeof() on it.

Comment: You *have* the size of the allocation; *you just allocated it* : `sizeof(short)*countMatches`.

Comment: Yeah but I need that information somewhere else, so i have to keep track of the array sizes somewhere myself?

Comment: *Only* in the case of `HeapAlloc`-ed memory, you can use [`HeapSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366706(v=vs.85).aspx) to obtain the allocation size, but read the documentation carefully.

Comment: I suppose it's more of a matter of purposely ignoring information, rather than not knowing, because this information isn't readily available. You did link to the documentation, and decided to not read it.

Comment: Shake off the downvotes. At least you asked a coherent question with minimal example code that reproduced the problem. That's more than a lot of users bother to do. Yes, it would be nice to read the documentation, though. The `sizeof` mistake is a fairly common one, and therefore it is fairly well-documented online. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) has an article about it. The underlying question about heap memory allocation is still a reasonable one, though.

Comment: @IInspectable I did, and it does not tell how to determine the size of an allocation. Since I heard about using sizeof() on arrays, I did not bother to search for alternative ways to do it.

Comment: There's a *See also* section at the bottom of the documentation, with a link to [heap functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711.aspx), that explains pretty much everything you need to now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HeapAlloc rounds up allocations to the nearest alignment. If you ask for 2 bytes, it will give you *at least* two bytes, but may give you more. As [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597.aspx) says:

> If the HeapAlloc function succeeds, it allocates at least the amount of memory requested.

The specific alignment that HeapAlloc uses is not documented, but if I remember correctly, all of the Heap Manager APIs use an 8-byte alignment on 32-bit x86 and a 16-byte alignment on 64-bit x86. [This old knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286470) jives with my recollection. Of course, because it is not explicitly documented and subject to change in future versions of Windows and/or on different architectures, you should not rely on hard-coded alignment values.

However, if these functions do allocate more memory than request, the caller *is* free to use all of that memory. To determine the actual size of the allocation, you call the [HeapSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366706.aspx) function. [Raymond Chen blogged about this some time ago](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120316-00/?p=8083).

So the behavior you're seeing actually makes sense, even though you are going about making the determination in entirely the wrong way. As has been pointed out in the comments already, `sizeof` doesn't tell you the size of the allocation. You need HeapSize to do that. All `sizeof` tells you is the size of the element `matches[lastMeal]` *at compile time*, which is *also* 8 bytes instead of 2 for alignment reasons.

As for your edit: best practice is to track this information yourself. Whenever you pass  a pointer, pass the size of the allocation along with it. Note that this should be the *expected* size of the allocation (the 2 bytes that you asked for), not the *actual* size of the allocation (the 8 bytes that the Heap Manager returned for internal alignment considerations). When you free the memory by calling `HeapFree`, it knows how big the actual allocation was and will free it as necessary. There is, however, no way for your client code to determine the size of the allocation that you initially requested, which is why you need to track it yourself.

Comment: What's more, `sizeof` calculates the size of an expression at compile time. It cannot possibly foresee the future, and determine the size of a `HeapAlloc` call at runtime.